# Convert string of list of dictionary to Python DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .JSON file which is around 3GB. I would like to read this JSON data and load it to pandas data frames. Below is what i did so far..

Step 1: Read JSON file

```
import pandas as pd
with open('MyFile.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

Step2: just take one component, since data is huge and i want to see how it looks

```
cp = data[0:1]
print(cp)

['{"reviewerID": "AO94DHGC771SJ", "asin": "0528881469", "reviewerName": "amazdnu", "helpful": [0, 0], "reviewText": "some review text...", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "Gotta have GPS!", "unixReviewTime": 1370131200, "reviewTime": "06 2, 2013"}\n']
```

Step3: to remove new line('\n') character

```
while ix<len(t):
    t[ix]=t[ix].rstrip("\n")
    ix+=1
```

Questions:

1. Why this JSON data is in string? Am I making any mistakes?
2. How do I convert it into dictionary?

What I tried?

1. I tried `b=dict(zip(t[0::2],t[1::2]))`,
   but get - 'dict' object not callable
2. Tried joining, but did not work though

Can any one please help me? Thanks!

Comment: You should use the `json` library to deserialize a json file into a python object. using `open` will read the file as a text file.Or you could use `pandas.read_json` to read directly into a dataframe if no major changes to the structure are necessary.

Comment: Is this a 3GB file with each line representing one independent JSON dict? Or is the _entire_ file, all lines combined, one JSON dict? Asked differently, is the closing bracket to the first opening bracket on the first or on the last line of the file?

Comment: you are right tobias_k, its a 3 gb file with each line representing one independent JSON dict

Answer (score 0):

Why haven't you tried `pandas.read_json`?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('MyFile.json')
```

Works for the example you posted!

```
In[82]: i = '{"reviewerID": "AO94DHGC771SJ", "asin": "0528881469", "reviewerName": "amazdnu", "helpful": [0, 0], "reviewText": "some review text...", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "Gotta have GPS!", "unixReviewTime": 1370131200, "reviewTime": "06 2, 2013"}'

In[83]: pd.read_json(i)
Out[83]: 
        asin  helpful  overall           reviewText  reviewTime     reviewerID reviewerName          summary  unixReviewTime
0  528881469        0        5  some review text...  06 2, 2013  AO94DHGC771SJ      amazdnu  Gotta have GPS!      1370131200
```